# Expected parameter value, got "è while sending an email using Amazon SES in C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I've been using Amazon SES to send an email with attachments. If I attach attachment with English names it is working correctly but if I attach chines resumes it is throwing an error Expected parameter value, got "è. The error description is not clear and I tried to encode with different formats but getting the same error.

Below is the code I'm using to construct mail message and send

```
public static MailResponse SendRawEmail(String from, List<string> to,List<string> ccAddresses,List<string> bccAddresses, String Subject, string body=null,List<string> attachments=null, String html = null,Salesforce.Contact[] contacts=null, String replyTo = null, String returnPath = null)
{
    MailResponse mresponse = new MailResponse();
    try
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);


       mailMessage.Body = body;

        mailMessage.Subject = Subject;
        mailMessage.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        foreach (string attachment in attachments)
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attachment));

        if (body != null)
        {
            AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
            mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
        }

        if (html != null)
        {
            AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");
            mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
        }

        RawMessage rawMessage = new RawMessage();
         Amazon.SimpleEmail.IAmazonSimpleEmailService ses;
        if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSRegion"]=="USWest2")
         ses = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"],Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
        else
            ses = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"],Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

        foreach (String toAddress in to)
        {
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = ConvertMailMessageToMemoryStream(mailMessage))
            {
                rawMessage.Data = memoryStream;
            }
            SendRawEmailRequest request = new SendRawEmailRequest();
            request.RawMessage = rawMessage;
            request.Source = from;
            request.Destinations.Add(toAddress);
            CallAmazonSES(request, ses);
            request.Destinations.Clear();
            mailMessage.To.Clear();
        }
        foreach (String ccAddress in ccAddresses)
        {
            mailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(ccAddress));
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = ConvertMailMessageToMemoryStream(mailMessage))
            {
                rawMessage.Data = memoryStream;
            }
            SendRawEmailRequest request = new SendRawEmailRequest();
            request.RawMessage = rawMessage;
            request.Source = from;
            request.Destinations.Add(ccAddress);
            CallAmazonSES(request, ses);
            request.Destinations.Clear();
            mailMessage.CC.Clear();
        }

        List<List<string>> bccAddressesList = Split(bccAddresses);
        foreach (List<String> bcclist in bccAddressesList)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = ConvertMailMessageToMemoryStream(mailMessage))
            {
                rawMessage.Data = memoryStream;
            }
            SendRawEmailRequest request = new SendRawEmailRequest();
            request.RawMessage = rawMessage;
            request.Source = from;

            request.Destinations.AddRange(bcclist);

            CallAmazonSES(request, ses);
        }


        mresponse.Response = "Mail sent succesfully";

    }
   catch (Exception ex)
    {
        mresponse.Response = "Mail failed due to " + ex.Message;
    }
    return mresponse;
}
```

> Stack trace :    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.HandleHttpWebErrorResponse(AsyncResult
>   asyncResult, WebException we)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.getResponseCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.endOperation[T](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Amazon.SimpleEmail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.SendRawEmail(SendRawEmailRequest
>   request)    at Blogic.CallAmazonSES(MailMessage mailMessage,
>   RawMessage rawMessage, String from, String to,
>   IAmazonSimpleEmailService ses) in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\TalentRover\App_Code\Blogic.cs:line 371    at
>   Blogic.SendRawCustomEmail(String from, List`1 ccAddresses, List`1
>   bccAddresses, String Subject, RequestArguments args, String mailField,
>   Boolean showOptout, String body, List`1 attachments, String html,
>   List`1 contacts, String replyTo, String returnPath, String contactId,
>   String callListId) in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\TalentRover\App_Code\Blogic.cs:line 236
>
> ```
>    Exception message : Expected parameter value, got "è"
> ```

link to complete code 
https://gist.github.com/lmedikonda/ec1315517bef421c49dd4912cb52e547

Comment: full exception text and call stack indicating line number?  [possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38304341/1132334)

Comment: Please add Exception message and stack trace in your question that'll help you to get answers quickly,

Comment: @MihirDave adding stack trace and exception message here

Comment: @Lax_me the call stack says that the exception was thrown by your `Blogic.CallAmazonSES` method, not `SendRawCustomEmail`. Post the code that actually throws and the *full* exception string. You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()`. This will include the message, call stack, and any inner exceptions

Comment: @Lax_me btw you can debug that code locally to check what's wrong. If a message body was invalid the code will still fail

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did the debugging in my local machine and I'm getting an exception when I'm calling Amazon SDK method SendRawEmail SendRawEmailResponse response = ses.SendRawEmail(request);

Comment: Getting this error only when I'm sending chinese attachment and I'm not getting an exception if I'm sending only body or english attachments

Comment: copied the complete code here https://gist.github.com/lmedikonda/ec1315517bef421c49dd4912cb52e547

Comment: @Lax_me and? Where did it throw? What was the full exception? What did the *message* look like? Use a *simple* example. One recipient, one message would be enough to reproduce this. Although the problem almost certainly is a bad conversion to UTF8. In any case this is far, far, far too much code to send an email message. Why does `SmptClient` appear here at all when the code actually wants to talk to AWS SES?

Comment: @Lax_me did you check the [SES docs for C#](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-net.html) ?